# Argument of type 'Map<any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<{}>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create an Rx.Observable from a Map object inside an Angular component and I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Map<any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<{}>'
```

The code works fine outside Angular (see: http://jsbin.com/tezohobudu/1/edit?js,console) so I don't understand why is not working in an Angular component. The component code is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  testOne(){
    //works on js collections
    const map = new Map();
    map.set(1, 'Hi');
    map.set(2, 'Bye');

    const mapSource = from(map);
    //output: [1, 'Hi'], [2, 'Bye']
    const subscribe = mapSource.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
}
```

package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "angular-tests",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get that error? Surely `from` expects an *array* of things, `of` is what you'd use for a single thing.

Comment: With "of" works (no error) but the map is taken as one thing and my understanding based on (<http://jsbin.com/tezohobudu/1/edit?js,console>) is that the map can be seen as an array of tuples, so I'll have two tuples  [1, 'Hi'] and [2, 'Bye']

Comment: A JavaScript Map is an Iterable and can therefore be used in for loops etc. But it isn't an ArrayLike object, since it's missing the length member and numbered members. You could use `from(Array.from(map))`, because `Array.from` accepts an Iterable and converts it to an Array.

Comment: Thank you Markai! from(Array.from(map)) has indeed worked as expected.